# ArcGIS error when using hfactor table in Path Distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.7

I am trying to calculate isochrones for sailing under various weather conditions.

Inputs for Path Distance
Input raster or feature source data: .shp with coastal points
Input cost raster: Raster of wind speed
Input horizontal raster: Raster of wind direction (0-360 degrees in integer format)
Horizontal factor: ASCII Table of 0 to 180 with corresponding values

I can use any other horizontal factor (Binary, Forward, Linear, Inverse Linear, etc) and get a valid result, but when I use a table, I receive `ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error. Failed to execute (PathDistance)`.

Anyone encountered this or found a workaround? I had to do a lot of troubleshooting, and at this point, I'm pretty confident it's something to do with using a table as the hfactor.

Comment: I am having the same issue but with a vertical factor table. I have compared it against a previously created table which does work but do not find any differences outside the numbers in the right column. Has anyone solved this issue yet?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a VfTable. After a few trials, I realized that when editing a working table and saving a copy, I did not save it as an ASCII file (ANSI formatting) but as UTF.

I realize this is an old question but anyone having this issue, try re-saving a copy as ASCII and running Path Distance again. It should work if that is what was causing the error, as was in my case.